# Is there any way to save my Hard Drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

I am having a HDD issue. Upon starting my PC this morning, I heard a "squeaking" noise coming from one of my HDDs. I believe this was the sound of the read/write head searching for something, and not finding it. The entire system was also unresponsive, though this was not my boot drive. Just a backup drive. I shutdown the system via the case power button. Not a great plan, but it seemed to be the only option. Upon rebooting the system, the HDD was showing up in disk management as unallocated and it needed initialized. It could not be initialized due to a "I/O Device error." I tried rebuilding the MBR using the AOMEI partition assistant. It also failed. I tried initializing  using the partition assistant, and that failed. I cleaned the disk using `diskpart` and it changed nothing. Does anyone have any ideas about this, or is the HDD just completely dead?

Comment: Sounds like a physical failure, possibly seized bearings. Time to replace it.

Comment: If the hard disk is still detected, the last thing you can try is get another hard disk with similar or bigger capacity and try to clone it. I have experience multiple HDD issues like that and some I managed to recover by cloning. Hopefully yours can be recovered the same way too.

Comment: @tcadidot0 - OP said it's a backup, so the original data can just be copied to a new drive. Zero effort, full reward ;)

Comment: If you decide to discard the drive, there are useful rare-earth magnets inside.

Comment: Oh I see.. I had to read the question again to find that _"this was not my boot drive"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am having a HDD issue. Upon starting my PC this morning, I heard a "squeaking" noise coming from one of my HDDs. I believe this was the sound of the read/write head searching for something, and not finding it. The entire system was also unresponsive, though this was not my boot drive. Just a backup drive. I shutdown the system via the case power button. Not a great plan, but it seemed to be the only option.

This reaction was perfect.

> Upon rebooting the system, the HDD was showing up in disk management as unallocated and it needed initialized. It could not be initialized due to a "I/O Device error." I tried rebuilding the MBR using the AOMEI partition assistant.

This reaction was bad.
Upon the "I/O Device error." you should have switched off the disc, installed Crystaldiskinfo (Windows) or preferably smartmontools (Windows and linux).
Both programs read out SMART information (self-diagnosis).

You would then reboot your machine (preferably linux) with the questionable disc being off. You would haved powered on the disc, checked its presence in disk management (windows) or linux (using the "lsblk" command) ran a

smartctl -a /dev/sdX > myreport.txt

replacing X by the drive letter learnt from the lsblk command.
In case of failures with your drive (being perhaps an external one in a box) you would have added the -d parameter like "-d sat" or some of its variants.
Upon generation of a report in the "myreport.txt" file you would have simply uploaded that file for discussion.

> It also failed. I tried initializing using the partition assistant, and that failed. I cleaned the disk using diskpart and it changed nothing.

Both actions correspond to playing unfortunately and not to diagnosing.

> Does anyone have any ideas about this, or is the HDD just completely dead?

According to your description assuming no power supply problem and no cable connection problem either I pretend that your disc is broken.